# Local JSON file stream to website

Tags: json, ajax, upload, stream, local

I am reallllly struggling with this and hopefully someone can let me know if it is possible or not...

So i have a JSON file that is updated with values from a simulation such as speed, location, current vehicle etc. I wish to have the ability to "stream" the JSON file currently in my documents to my website OR have the JSON file re-uploaded to my website every (say 10) seconds. I's this possible with PHP / Javascript / AJAX at all?

I am fairly new to web development so i apologise in advance... if anyone could help me out with this or point me in the right direction i would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

It should be very straightforward to POST your JSON file to a web service, there are many ways to do this. You could simply setup a scheduled task using curl and bash/powershell.

It would be very easy likewise to use Node.js (server side Javascript) to do this.

This Node.js script will post the contents of sim_data.json to a given Url every 60 seconds:

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

function postSimData() {

    let simData = fs.readFileSync('./sim_data.json', 'utf8');

    var options = {
        // Change to whatever you need.
        url: "http://localhost:8080/post_sim_data",
        method: "POST",
        body: simData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    console.log('Posting sim data..');
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('error:', error);
        } else {
            console.log('Response: Headers:', response && response.headers);
        }
    });
}

/* Post data every 60000 milliseconds (one minute) */
setInterval(postSimData, 60000);
```